# track which line jsPdf is on when it splits text

Tags: jspdf

Am using jsPdf to generate some documentation and on occasion a long description field runs over a few lines. This is managed fine using the'maxWidth' option in .text method, to wrap the text, however what then results is losing track of what height to place the next line of text.

Has anyone found a way to effectively track height of wrapped text so can space next paragraph ok?